# How to add a shell item to a Windows right click context menu?

Tags: vb.net, powershell, contextmenu, vb.net-2010, right-click

I created a small antivirus in VB.NET.  I need to add this functionality so that my software can start scanning the file which is submitted to it via a windows right click menu like in other antivirus software "scan this file".

What code should be added into my scanner to accept the parameters passed by shell extension?

Here's my code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim time As Integer = 0
    Dim array As Array

    Private Sub OpenButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim selectedFile As String = String.Empty
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        selectedFile = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        If (selectedFile IsNot Nothing) Then
            TextBox1.Text = selectedFile
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ScanButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        On Error Resume Next

        Dim scan As New Vscan(TextBox1.Text)
        scan.Start()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Please view this image to better understand what I am looking for:

[image: Please check this image to better understand what I am looking for.]

Comment: you need to register your app as a explorer shell extension.

Comment: i use                                                               Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Scan with Apro]
@="Scan with Apro"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Scan with Apro\command]
@="\"C:\\Apro.exe\" \"%1\""

Comment: application started and but do nothing

Comment: does your code read the commandline?  see also [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/174369/How-to-Write-Windows-Shell-Extension-with-NET-Lang) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/512956/NET-Shell-Extensions-Shell-Context-Menus)

Comment: @Plutonix which code should be added into my scanner to accept the parameters passed by shell extension

Comment: no my code not read commandline u can see my code above

Comment: `System.Environment.CommandLine` or `System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`

Comment: @Plutonix how to use this:: System.Environment.CommandLine or System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()

Comment: add it to your code and see! one returns a string, the other a string array of the commandline.  parse it in formload (for main forms) or `Sub Main`